How does 自由に不自由していない work here?
Character B, who is essentially a pirate, is challenging another character to a dual, promising that he will give up his armor that the other character is searching for (A was sent by the Bakufu to collect specific weapons and armor by defeating their holders). B says that he has a few conditions in this arrangement:

A: 言っておくが、現役の海賊相手にお目こぼしはありえんぞ
B: 幕府からお目こぼしをもらわなきゃいけないほど自由に不自由してねえよ‌
ただちょっとこっちのメンツを立ててほしいんだ

How does 自由に affect 不自由しない here? Can you really be "freely not in need" of something like money or in this case the Bakufu giving you special treatment by overlooking your actions as a pirate? Does this not seem redundant at all?

Is this dialogue, by any chance, from 刀語?

図星です。１００点満点。面白いアニメだと思います。

Xに不自由する is a set phrase that means "not to have enough X to use freely", "to have difficulties regarding X", or "to suffer from a shortage of X". This phrase is used to express hardship one suffers in daily life. Common examples:

生活に不自由する
お金に不自由する
日々の食べ物に不自由する

自由に不自由していない sounds like a rhetorical expression, but B is saying he already has enough freedom and doesn't need any special treatment from the Bakufu.
